# jqGrid loadComplete function gets called multiple times,Also check boxes requires multiple clicks

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Im having a problem with loadComplete function of jqGrid.Its getting fired multiple times when i navigate the data using pager and trying to click a selectAll checkbox.

For e.g.
I'm currently displaying 15 rows of data on the grid,loadComplete is called once when i'm on first page.
Now when i click next from the pager to view next 15 rows,loadComplete is called twice when i'm on the second page.
Now when i again click next to view another 15 rows of data,this time i'm on 3rd page and loadComplete gets called thrice.

Also the check boxes from the second page requires 2 clicks in order to select or deselect.

My question is that does anyone know why this is happening? And if yes than can you please guide me on what should i do in order to solve this problem.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually this means you are binding your event multiple times. It sounds like the button "next" has some code that would resemble

```
$(function () {
   $('#nextButton').click(function(){loadComplete})
});
```

In the above example when ever the page is ready the click event gets bound to the function loadComplete. When ever your page is ready, it increase the time the function is going to occur by 1.